# Data not being passed to show function

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following questionnaire controller with the some functions, i am facing problem in the show function where the data is not being passed to the show view, although it is being saved in my database

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Questionnaire;
class QuestionnaireController extends Controller
{
    //
   public function create() {

        return view('questionnaires.create');
    }

   public function store( ) {


    $data = request()->validate([

        'title' => 'required',
        'purpose' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;


    $questionnaire = \App\Questionnaire::create($data);



    return redirect('/questionnaires/'.$questionnaire->id);


   }

   public function show(\App\Questionnaire $questionnaire) {

        return view('questionnaires.show', compact('questionnaire'));
   }
}
```

The following is the show view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{{$questionnaire->title}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
return redirect('/questionnaires/')->with('questionnaire', $questionnaire);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show(\App\Questionnaire $questionnaire) {
    return view('questionnaires.show')->with(compact('questionnaire'));
}
```

Try this solution.

Comment: Nothing happens although if i do dd($data) the right parameters are being passed

Comment: <div class="card-header">{{ dd($questionnaire->title) }}</div> returns null

Comment: try echo full object. If object is null, laravel will make a 404, then i think your object isnt null. Try <div class="card-header">{{ $questionnaire }}</div> to see your fields

Answer (score 0):

The following code gave the me the desired result

```
  public function show($id) {

   $questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($id);


    return view('questionnaires.show')->with(compact('questionnaire'));
}
```